# Can't set scrollTop of HTMLElement in useEffect without timeout function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a text log component that I want to scroll to the bottom whenever it receives a new log entry, so I have it set the parent's `scrollTop` to it's `scrollHeight` in `useEffect()`. However, this has no effect:

```
const Log = ({ entries }: LogProps) => {
    const logRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (logRef && logRef.current) {
            let parent = logRef.current.parentNode as HTMLDivElement
            parent.scrollTop = parent.scrollHeight;
        }
    })
    return (
        <Module className="log" title="Text Log">
            <div ref={logRef} className="log__entries">
                ...
            </div>
        </Module>

    )
}
```

This code on the other hand, works:

```
...
useEffect(() => {
    if (logRef && logRef.current) {
        let parent = logRef.current.parentNode as HTMLDivElement
        setTimeout(() => {
            parent.scrollTop = parent.scrollHeight;
        }, 100)
    }     
})
...
```

On my machine, I can set the timeout as low as 39, and it'll work consistently. Lower numbers have sporadic success. Presumably that number will vary by some performance metric, but I have no idea.

Console logging shows that the ref exists, and it does have height enough to scroll by the time `useEffect()` triggers. Logging before and after `parent.scrollTop = parent.scrollHeight;` reveals that `scrollTop` doesn't change.

Am I misunderstanding how `useEffect()` works, is it because I'm setting the parent's `scrollTop`, or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by making a few changes:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  logRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end' })
}, [entries])
```

You can see list of browsers supporting `scrollIntoView` feature at [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).
If you want more browsers to support then you can install this tiny npm package called [smoothscroll-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smoothscroll-polyfill).

Comment: That solves my needing to reference the parent, but that call still isn't working unless it's within a timeout function for whatever reason.

Comment: Is your `enteries` coming from some API call? If yes, is your state updating properly? Can you share a reproducible example? As it's working fine for me.